# Does Azue pipeline parameters can only been used for component parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, azure

Can I consume or use a pipeline parameter in addition to the component parameters?

For example, I'm trying to publish a pipeline into a pipeline endpoint. The pipelineParameters should include the input_data and output_data_path.

my pipeline looks like this:

```
class PublishedPipeline(AMLPipelineHelper):
    def build(self, config):
        input_step = self.module("step1")
        output_step = self.component_load("data_transfer")
    
    def pipeline_function(input_data, output_data_path):
        step1 = input_step(input_file=input_data)
        step2 = output_step(
             source_data=step1.outputs.output_path
        }
        step2.outputs.destination_data.configure(
             path_on_datastore=output_data_path
        )
    return pipeline_function
```

The pipeline only consume input_data parameter as the first step parameter but can not consume the output_data_path as the output setting of step2. The runtime pipeline shows outputs.destination_data.path_on_datastore on step2 @@output_data_path@@. And It didn't be replaced by the pass in pipeline parameters. Can anyone help me solve this problem? How can I use the pipeline parameters in addition to the component parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Updated azure-ml-component version to 0.9.9.post3, now it works.